# How to use XUnit with Visual studio to unit test code running in a remote process

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, resharper, solidworks

We are writing plugins for the [Solidworks](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Welcome.htm) CAD system. Writing an addin involves compiling a DLL, registering it and then starting solidworks. Code in the dll can be configured to execute as soon as solidworks starts.

What I would like to do is craft a special DLL so that it runs a series of unit tests or a single unit test from visual studio and reports the results back to visual studio in the standard way.

We are happy to use either the standard visual studio test or resharper test system.

Is it possible to write an extension to the unit test system to achieve this. If so how difficult is this to achieve. Perhaps there are extensions that already do something similar for other plugin type environments that need testing.

Comment: testing solidworks addins can be very painful...

Comment: When I'm testing solidworks add-ins code, I find it quite easier to marshal.GetActiveObject("SolidWorks.Application") to get sldworks object and then simply run through it my code. I think this can be incoporated in a unitest so you're basically mocking up solidworks without having to compile and regasm the dll and wait for sldwrks to start.

Comment: I forgot I asked this. We have almost finished writing an extension to xunit to allow true in process unit testing. It will include a solidworks addin that includes a WCF service. The WCF service is part of an xunit extension we wrote. In the end the process is completely transparent and the unit tests are even debuggable. Hopefully we will get it finished on Monday and we will release it. State tuned.

Comment: The out of process xunit testing part is pretty much ready. You can see this here. We will also create a solidworks specific extension to this. https://github.com/Weingartner/OutOfProcessTest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We wrote a plugin for XUnit that solves this problem

https://github.com/Weingartner/XUnitRemote

and a specific solution using the above is for unit testing solidworks

https://github.com/Weingartner/SolidworksAddinFramework

An example test with example custom **facts**

```
namespace XUnitRemote.Test
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _Output;

        public Tests(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            _Output = output;
        }

        [SampleProcessFact]
        public void OutOfProcess()
        {
            _Output.WriteLine("Process name: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
            Assert.Equal(5, 3);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void InProcess()
        {
            _Output.WriteLine("Process name: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
            Assert.Equal(5, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

for your custom process you need to write a few hooks so look in the project to get the details on how to do this.

Comment: We still have problems getting it to work with solidworks. Solidworks does funky stuff with app domains and weird bad stuff happens. The principle is sound but still needs some work.

Comment: you're doing manual testing meanwhile? what sort of plugins are you writing? you're welcome to check mine: https://github.com/jliliamen/power-sm

Comment: No we are doing automatic testing but we have found that the COM calls are extremely slow when run out of process. The new framework will run in process and should be faster.

Comment: The addin framework and testframework for solidworks is now working well enough to be usable. https://github.com/Weingartner/SolidworksAddinFramework Let me know if it is useful to you.

Comment: It took a bit of work but we now dispatch tests in process and running on the correct thread so there  is very little overhead from COM. Tests that were taking 20 seconds out of process now take less than a second running in process. :)

Comment: im developing an addin for solidworks 'ill be sure to use it im not really savvy when it comes to unit testing will have to read more abt xunit